# $.ajax.done works on Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a very simple AJAX request with jQuery and PHP. This is my code

```
var request = $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "Url.php",
    data: { param: valueParam },
    dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(html) {
   alert('Hello');
});
```

The code works perfect in Firefox 38.0.5 but not works in Chrome 43.0.2357.124m.

The problem in Chrome is the follow: the "Url.php" returns a pair name-value. If it returns a value distinct than null, then the alert is not displayed (and there isn't any error in the console). But if the url return a null value, the alert is displayed. I tried ctrl+F5 but not works.

In Firefox works good in both cases.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by null value? The string `null`, or an empty response? What if you specify `dataType: "text"`?

Comment: The response is {"empresa": value} if value = null (not string), the alert is displayed. If the value is != null the alert is not displayed. If I put dataType="text" anything changes.

Comment: That looks like JSON, not HTML.

Comment: Yes, but I try to put dataType: "json" and the result is the same: not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when I was firing the ajax request. I was doing it in "onchange" (of a input text with jQuery autocomplete) jQuery event. When I select an item of the list of autocomplete, the onchange() event is not raised in Chrome (yes in Firefox).

So I fire the ajax request in jQuery "focusout" event and works in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Does fail function return something?

```
request.done(function( msg ) {
  console.log(msg);
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  console.log("Request failed: "+textStatus);
});
```

Comment: No, this isn't return anything